# trying to extract text from image using pytesseract function(image_to_string)one of the image it is extracting it in some different languages

Tags: python, tesseract

Trying to extract text from screenshot image, it is working for max images but for some extracting text in some different languages

```py
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
output=pytesseract.image_to_string(PIL.Image.open(r'C:\Users\ab2\Desktop\Use_case\default.png').convert("RGB"), lang='eng')
```

Expected:

```
Your iphone could not be activated because the activation server is temporarily unavailable. Try connecting your iPhone to iTunes to activate it, or try again in a couple of minutes.
```

Actual:

```
w

( am cu-nu Not Activate Whune

Your wihrme um‘ um no ac|vvaled
hm, mu m» ,mmmon «ewev vs‘
1emmr,m\\,r mwmxame Try
conn£chr\u JULJ vP\7:me ﬁn mums to
acma(r3r\ m u», again m a Couple‘ 0!
mmu(e~.

H (his woman pnwsv; Lomact
Ar3p\e Supp'.rV.'.1lunp\e cum:<upDur\

H, Aunm
```

Comment: Expected result is :   Your iphone could not be activated because the activation server is temporarily unavailable. Try connecting your iPhone to iTunes to activate it, or try again in a couple of minutes.

Comment: That is not a different language. It is garbled English. The problem isn't the language, it is that your image is not clear enough for pytesseract to make sense of it.